# Django's default behaviour for web/http caching

Tags: django, http-caching

My question is referring to [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#upstream-caches) of the django docs.

In there, there is a paragraph that reads:

> Note that the caching middleware already sets the cache header's max-age with the value of the CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS setting. If you use a custom max_age in a cache_control decorator, the decorator will take precedence, and the header values will be merged correctly.

My interpretation is that, by default, responses from django server-end would have "Cache-Control:max-age=600" in their http header sections, unless some http-cache-related decorator is used to modify the "Cache-Control" header.

I performed a quick experiment to verify my interpretation above. Surprisingly, when no http-cache-related is used on the view, the response generated has **NO "Cache-Control" header at all**.

Why am I seeing a different result from what the official docs describes? Have I misunderstood the outlined paragraph?

Also, when there is no "Cache-Control" header in a response, can I safely assume there's no http caching involved (ie. no cached response would be used)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not happen "by default". Two conditions must be met for Django to attach the `Cache-Control` header:

1. You must have a caching backend set up, with either `CACHES` (Django 1.3+) or `BACKEND` (Django <1.3).
2. You must add the cache middleware to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) for details.

As far as caching in the absence of a `Cache-Control` header, that then becomes the decision of the web browser or client in general. `Cache-Control` gives directives that *must* be followed, but browsers already generally cache on their own, so its real purpose is usually to *prevent* caching in certain scenarios, rather than enabling it.

Comment: Chris - Thx. Your answer is great, especially on pointing out the design purpose of `Cache-Control`. 

I am fairly new to caching for web development. I want to learn more about how to apply it to develop/design better web app. Do you know any literature/resources that might help me? They don't have to be django, as I am more interested in learning the higher-level application of caching.

Also, a quick, and maybe dumb, question for you. Does reloading/refreshing a page on browser always force the browser to get the response from server, instead of the cached copy (assuming it's available)?

Comment: Not always. Generally, the simple refresh just requests the actual HTML document again. Most browsers have a keyboard shortcut that lets you do a full refresh. Usually CTRL+SHIFT+R in Windows. IE is a little more finicky, and doesn't like to let go of cached resources as easily.

Comment: For Django 1.7 only condition #2 needs to be met for the cache-control header to be set. The reason why is that even if you don't set CACHES in your settings by default lomem cache will be set. `{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}`